# How to customize the superuser creation in Django when using a proper User model?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models defined on my user's app:

```py
class Address(models.Model):
    tower = models.SmallIntegerField()
    floor = models.SmallIntegerField()
    door = models.CharField(max_length=5)


class User(AbstractUser):
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "address"]
```

That is, I'm extending the Django's base `User` object, by adding a one to one field to a table which handles the address for each user.

But taking this approach, then when I try to create a superuser account from CLI, with `python manage.py createsuperuser`, the following happens:

```bash
Username: admin
Email address: admin@admin.com
Address (Address.id): 1
Error: address instance with id 1 does not exist.
```

So Django is requesting me to enter an address id but as no address is yet stored in the database, that error is raised.

Is there any way to create a superuser by entering both fields from `User` model and from `Address` model, and creating a record in both tables? That is, something like:

```bash
Username: admin
Email address: admin@admin.com
Tower: 1
Floor: 12
Door: A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your own command to create super user(customized)

## /user/management/commands/createmysuperuser.py

```
from user.models import User, Address 
 from django.core.management import BaseCommand, CommandParser 
  
  
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'create super user with address'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        username = input("Username: ")
        email = input("Email address:")
        tower = input("Tower:")
        floor = input("Floor:")
        door = input("Door:")

        address = Address.objects.create(...)
        user = User.objects.create(...)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach! But, would be possible to, instead of creating a new custom management command, overwrite the default `createsuperuser`?

Comment: Uhm... I think overriding default command is not possible. Also, even if possible, overrding default command is not a good idea. Is there a reason not to create a new command?

Answer (score 0):

You can also override createsuperuser.

1. Create a file `managers.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.conf import settings

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    see https://dev.to/earthcomfy/getting-started-custom-user-model-5hc
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifier
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an email address'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

2. Within your `user.models.py`:

- `from .managers import CustomUserManager()`
- within your custom `User` class, include the line `objects = CustomUserManager()`